Can difference quotient sets be null?
Recently, there are several questions regarding what the difference quotient set - $\{\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}: x \neq y\}$ of a non-linear (or, more precisely, non-affine) $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ may be. See this question on whether the difference quotient set may be contained in the irrationals; this question on whether it may be contained in the irrationals, provided that $f$ is measurable; and this question on whether it can be nowhere dense. The first two questions have both received positive answers, while the third remains open. The current question is an alteration of the third question, where instead of the topological notion of nowhere dense, we instead ask whether it can be Lebesgue-null. More precisely,

Does there exist a non-affine $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. the set,
$$\{\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}: x \neq y\}$$
is Lebesgue-null?

I’ve discovered a solution assuming the continuum hypothesis, which I’m posting together with this question. But I’d be happy to see an answer which does not depend on CH.

There is something about this topic on the Arxiv if you might be interested. It's not clear to me if the results there help to prove either my (or your) problems.

Proposition: Assume the continuum hypothesis. If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a co-meager set, then there exists a non-affine $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. its difference quotient set is contained within $A$.
Proof: Let $\{r_\lambda\}_{\lambda < \omega_1}$ be an enumeration of reals of order type $\omega_1$. We inductively construct functions $\{f_\lambda\}_{\lambda < \omega_1}$ s.t. $f_\lambda$ is a function from the countable set $\{r_\kappa\}_{\kappa < \lambda}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $f_{\lambda_1} \subset f_{\lambda_2}$ for all $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 < \omega_1$.
We start with $f_0 = \varnothing$. For limit ordinals $\lambda$, we let $f_\lambda = \cup_{\kappa < \lambda} f_\kappa$. Finally, consider the case where $\lambda = \kappa + 1$ is a successor ordinal. Note that $f_\kappa \subset f_\lambda$ already determines $f_\lambda$ except $f_\lambda(r_\kappa)$. Note that $A^c$ is meager. Since translations and scalings are homeomorphisms of the reals, they send $A^c$ to meager sets. Thus,
$$(\bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} [(r_\kappa - r_\alpha)A^c + f_\kappa(r_\alpha)]) \cup (\{\frac{f_\kappa(r_\alpha) - f_\kappa(r_\beta)}{r_\alpha - r_\beta} \cdot (r_\kappa - r_\theta) + f_\kappa(r_\theta): \alpha, \beta, \theta < \kappa, \alpha \neq \beta\})$$
is a countable union of meager sets (the set on the right is countable, hence meager), whence meager itself. By Baire category theorem, its complement is nonempty, whence we may define $f_\lambda(r_\kappa)$ to be any real number outside the set above.
This concludes the inductive construction. Now, let $f = \cup_{\lambda < \omega_1} f_\lambda$. Then $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $r_\alpha, r_\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha \neq \beta$. We need to show that $\frac{f(r_\alpha) - f(r_\beta)}{r_\alpha - r_\beta} \in A$. Since $\frac{f(r_\alpha) - f(r_\beta)}{r_\alpha - r_\beta} = \frac{f(r_\beta) - f(r_\alpha)}{r_\beta - r_\alpha}$, we may assume WLOG that $\alpha > \beta$. Then,
$$\frac{f(r_\alpha) - f(r_\beta)}{r_\alpha - r_\beta} = \frac{f_{\alpha + 1}(r_\alpha) - f_\alpha(r_\beta)}{r_\alpha - r_\beta}$$
By the inductive construction, $f_{\alpha + 1}(r_\alpha) \notin (r_\alpha - r_\beta)A^c + f_\alpha(r_\beta)$, or, equivalently, $\frac{f_{\alpha + 1}(r_\alpha) - f_\alpha(r_\beta)}{r_\alpha - r_\beta} \notin A^c$, so $\frac{f(r_\alpha) - f(r_\beta)}{r_\alpha - r_\beta} \in A$, as desired.
Finally, we note that $f$ is not affine. Indeed, this follows from simply noting, by the inductive construction, that,
$$f(r_2) = f_3(r_2) \neq \frac{f_2(r_1) - f_2(r_0)}{r_1 - r_0} \cdot (r_2 - r_0) + f_2(r_0) = \frac{f(r_1) - f(r_0)}{r_1 - r_0} \cdot (r_2 - r_0) + f(r_0)$$
So, $\frac{f(r_2) - f(r_0)}{r_2 - r_0} \neq \frac{f(r_1) - f(r_0)}{r_1 - r_0}$, whence $f$ is not affine. $\square$
Now, the result easily follows by observing there is a co-meager set which is null. (By taking the countable intersection of a sequence of open dense sets whose Lebesgue measures decrease to $0$, say.)
Remark: The same argument shows that, assuming CH (or, in this case, Martin’s Axiom would also suffice), we may construct a non-affine $f$ whose difference quotient set lies within any pre-fixed co-null set.
